# How to get the SHAP values of each feature?

Tags: python, machine-learning, shap

I am currently working with the SHAP library, I already generated my charts with the avg contribution of each feature, however I would like to know the exact value that is plotted on the chart

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd  
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import shap


boston = load_boston()
regr = pd.DataFrame(boston.data)
regr.columns = boston.feature_names
regr['MEDV'] = boston.target

X = regr.drop('MEDV', axis = 1)
Y = regr['MEDV']

fit = LinearRegression().fit(X, Y)

explainer = shap.LinearExplainer(fit, X, feature_dependence = 'independent')
# I used 'independent' because the result is consistent with the ordinary 
# shapely values where `correlated' is not

shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X)

shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X, plot_type = 'bar')
```

[image]

How can I get the exact values that are depicted of the chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
pd.DataFrame((zip(X.columns[np.argsort(np.abs(shap_values).mean(0))],
np.abs(shap_values).mean(0))), columns=["feature", "importance" ]).sort_values(by="importance", ascending=False)
```

Reference [GitHub](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/632)

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer is wrong, the labels are incorrect.

Here is the corrected version:

```
pd.DataFrame((zip(X.columns[np.argsort(np.abs(shap_values).mean(0))][::-1],
-np.sort(-np.abs(shap_values).mean(0)))),
columns=["feature", "importance"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
features = X.columns
mask = np.abs(shap_values).mean(0).argsort()[::-1]
features[mask]
```

---

```
Index(['LSTAT', 'DIS', 'RAD', 'RM', 'TAX', 'PTRATIO', 'NOX', 'ZN', 'CRIM', 'B',
       'CHAS', 'INDUS', 'AGE'],
      dtype='object')
```